# Calling external Vimeo API from Angular $http

Tags: angularjs, vimeo

I've been trying to call an external API (Vimeo) from my AngularJS code, but all I get back is a 304 Not Modified.
My code:

```
this.$scope.$safeApply(() => {
    this.$http.jsonp('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/75532980.json?callback=?')
        .success((r) => {
            this.$log.info("Success: " + r);
        })
        .error((e) => {
            this.$log.info("Error: " + e);
        });
});
```

The odd thing is when I call the same URL from fiddler, everything seems ok and I get 200 response with the correct JSON.

Comment: Have look at this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956768/angularjs-is-caching-jsonp-by-default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PZ7rQXb3guREqGFsodHX?p=preview

I took the answer from: [AngularJS is caching JSONP by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956768/angularjs-is-caching-jsonp-by-default)

You add a timestamp to your query so it is not cached by angular. Also, I modified the value of your callback to JSON_CALLBACK as per doc ([AngularJS $http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)).

> Relative or absolute URL specifying the destination of the request. Should contain JSON_CALLBACK string.

```
$http.jsonp('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/75532980.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&_=' + (new Date().getTime()))
    .success(function (r) {
        $log.info("Success: " + r);
    })
    .error(function (e) {
        $log.info("Error: " + e);
    });
```